# How can i disable/remove context menu from combobox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have created an editable `JComboBox`. I want to add specific context menu but default context menu appears when right click.

Is there a way to remove it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkZoy.png]

Comment: There is no default context menu on an editable combo box, unless this is a LAF specific implementation. Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the popup menu of the editor of the combo box by using:

```
ComboBoxEditor editor = comboBox.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();
textField.setComponentPopupMenu(...);
```